# How to serialize a dictionary to a yaml file in c#

Tags: c#, yaml

I'm looking for an easy way to serialize dictionary (string key value pairs) to a yaml file in .net core c#

I checked [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet), and can not find a solution quick in docs

Comment: Check out YamlDotNet library perhaps https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet

Comment: yes :) the answer below is usefull for some people - it would definetly save my time if I would find it here. YamlDotNet documentation is not so good indexed by google as stack overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using YamlDotNet:

```cs
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("key", "value");
dictionary.Add("key2", "value2");
var serializer = new SerializerBuilder().Build();
var yaml = serializer.Serialize(dictionary);
Console.WriteLine(yaml);
```

Output:

```yaml
key: value
key2: value2
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vadyyf